# Spark application override yarn-site.xml config parameters

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

I need to override one Yarn configuration parameter in `yarn-site.xml` when I submit a Spark application.  Can I pass it as an extra param to `spark-submit`?

The parameter I want to override is `yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use --conf while submitting the job with spark-submit

```
--conf "yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled"
```

Or you can also set inside your program with the code as `SparkSession.conf.set`

From the doc

> Configuration for a Spark application. Used to set various Spark
>   parameters as key-value pairs.
>
> Most of the time, you would create a SparkConf object with new
>   SparkConf(), which will load values from any spark.* Java system
>   properties set in your application as well. In this case, parameters
>   you set directly on the SparkConf object take priority over system
>   properties.
>
> For unit tests, you can also call new SparkConf(false) to skip loading
>   external settings and get the same configuration no matter what the
>   system properties are.
>
> All setter methods in this class support chaining. For example, you
>   can write new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My app").

Comment: This worked.  Can I include this in the `spark-defaults.conf` file instead of passing it to `spark-submit`?

Comment: you dont need to spark-defaults.conf file  to pass through spark-submit if it is present in the spark/conf/ directory it reads itself